# Elementary argument that Ohm's law is nonclassical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

The freshman physics texts that I have to hand (Purcell, Feynman lectures) seem to invoke Ohmic behavior of materials without explicit justification in terms of microscopic models or experiment. Jackson (sec. 7.5) wanders through the phenomenology without ever giving much of a microscopic description, just some footnotes that admit tersely to the existence of quantum mechanics. Surprisingly, the most illuminating discussion of the microscopic picture that I was able to find was not in these venerated tomes but in the web site [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html#c1), which does seem to suggest that the ultimate explanation is inherently quantum-mechanical.

Is there any elementary argument to the effect that Ohm's law must have a nonclassical explanation?

As a sample of the kind of elementary argument I have in mind, there is the fact that classical physics can't explain the stability of atoms or bulk matter. My argument to this effect would be the following. We know from Earnshaw's theorem that there can't be a static equilibrium. But if it's not a static equilibrium, then we expect charges to be accelerating, and then they should radiate, which should rob the system of its energy, causing it to collapse.

Comment: For electric current flowing through ionized gas (plasma) we also have Ohm's law; but a purely classical theory (scattering of charged particles etc.) explains it all just fine. The temperature dependence of conductivity of metals is opposite to that of plasma, and it is an indication of quantum physics behind it.

Comment: Oh man, I had no idea this question went so deep- thanks for bringing it up. In my own simplistic world view I always assumed that the linear proportionality between effort and flow through a restriction was grounded in very simple, "common-sense" explanations and I eagerly await the insights of the experts on this matter. Happy new year to you- NN

Comment: I was under the impression that Ohm's law was quite general, and not limited to either quantum or classical systems. Isn't a variant even true for water in pipes?
It is true that classical models of conductivity like the Drude model don't work well for metals, which I think is what some of those authors are alluding to. But seems different to me than saying that Ohm's law is fundamentally based on QM.

Comment: @MaximUmansky: *The temperature dependence of conductivity of metals is opposite to that of plasma, and it is an indication of quantum physics behind it.* I guess the temperature dependence in metals has to do with the smearing of the occupation numbers near the Fermi level, which is a quantum mechanical effect. But I would also think that someone who didn't know the actual explanation could give a pretty plausible explanation for this trend. At higher temperature, the mean time between collisions would go down.

Comment: @Ben Crowell At higher temperature, the cross-section of collisions between charged particles (the Coulomb cross-section) becomes smaller so the mean time between collisions actually should increase. That's why at higher temperature the conductivity of plasma would increase. At least that's what happens in low-density, high-temperature `classical' plasmas. The fact that metals behave the opposite way is an indication that electric conductivity there is governed by quantum physics.